# Store an xsl variable for use in xsl value-of XPath string

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath

I realize that I lack sample XML here, however I believe my question is quite simple. With this XSL statement:

```
<xsl:variable name="defID" select="check/check-content-ref/@name" />
```

If I then wanted to use my "defID" variable in a `"value-of" select=""` statement how would I do this?

```
<xsl:value-of select="//*[@id='$defID']/metadata/description" />
```

The example above does not work. Clearly my syntax is incorrect, but myriad google searches do not reveal my syntactic error. Do I need to construct a whole string and *then* store it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not enclose the variable in quotes, when referring to it.

Comment: Thank you thank you! I knew it was something simple, but sometimes the simple questions are the hardest to answer. Everyone speaks at a college level and I just need kindergarten help!